# Need help with multiple loop efficiency

Tags: c#, java, vba

I am writing a routine which works out the accruals of certain benefits to people within a given month and the dates of payment of those accruals.

There are a few things to loop through and I am wondering how to increase the efficiency of the loop structure (or use alternatives).

When I take a certain benefit, I have to work out whether it is simple or complex. Simple means you get paid x every 14 days. Complex means a few things:

- that you get paid every x days, x can be defined.
- the amount depends on whether you have worked each day (so I need to look up and see if this person works a weekend, when they are taking holidays)
- the benefit can be suspended over certain periods of the year (e.g. school term holidays, only between 1 April and 23 August)

I am looking for some patterns somewhere, whether they be in a book or on a website. I am not asking anyone to design it for me.

I have tried some shortcuts with a few things:

1. I have taken holidays and serialised the dates into a string, and then just use a standard InString function to check if the data is in there
2. Creating arrays I can check (in some cases, the InString seems to work faster), rather than looping through a recordset
3. Using simple SQL statements (SELECT ixHoliday from tblHoliday Where tblHoliday.dtHoliday = dtInspected)

However, the table I am using creates individual holiday days (it reads off another system). This helps with this year's booked holidays but does not help with Easter etc (unless i eneter them in - and I have the algorithm for that). The problem comes in years to come, where I make simplifying assumptions.

This is used to prepare 5 year forecasts.

I am taking a profiler to the design shortly, but was wondering about any resource about structuring these kind of patterns.

Comment: Sorry, I see that you tried to give lots of detail, but you really didn't make it clear exactly what it is that you're trying to speed up.  Perhaps if you included some code, it would help?

Comment: I concur with mquander. It's hard to optimize code site unseen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment on the rest of your algorithm, as it sounds highly domain-specific, but surely this

> I have taken holidays and serialised the dates into a string, and then just use a standard InString function to check if the data is in there

is not the fastest/easiest/most efficient way to test if a collection contains a Date of a given value.

Regardless of what language you are using (and you did not specify), any modern language/library (certainly C# and Java) have container objects and structures which offer operations to test if an object is contained in some list that doesn't devolve into serialization and String parsing.

Comment: My thoughts exactly - nice answer.  @Paddy - look into Hashtable (Java) and HashTable / Dictionary(Of DateTime) (.Net) for near-optimal ways of storing your holiday days.  BitSet (Java) / BitArray (.Net) would be even more performant but require a little extra thought as to how to use.

Comment: Thanks guys - will try through optimiser. There is a pile of code. Might work better top post some higher level psuedo-code if profiler brings no joy.